# Goodman furnace flame out

Tags: furnace

New Goodman furnace.  Starts ok, but then the flame blows out when the main blower fan starts.
Furnace attempts to restart, but flames out again immediately.

I get no error codes.

I dont think it’s flame sensor, or primary limit.
But I will check that.

I suspect an air/gas mix problem because the unit runs longer with top cover off (ie the burner area open)

When the top cover is on, the furnace often fails to ignite. Burners start and then extinguish, and the cover physically sucks in when the flame ignites (sucking tighter to the furnace chassis)

When the burner flames out there is an audible “popping” as the burners attempt to restart, but flames go out immediately.

Problem much worse when top cover is on, but even when cover is off the furnace will not remain lit

I have 2inch intake and exhaust lines, each with 5 elbows and 6 ft in length.

I am at an altitude of 6500 ft, but do not have a high altitude gas kit

Comment: Are you sure the flames are "blowing" out and not being shut off by some sensor that is detecting something wrong?    The cover "sucking in" would be normal if it is on the intake side of the air flow.  The combustion chamber should not be affected by that, by the cover being on or off if it is a cover for the intake plenum.  If the duct work is too small or blocked that might explain the cover flexing abnormally, and maybe there is an air flow detector sensing no flow and shutting the flame off.  Also if its a plenum cover, removing it might change air flow so that sensor acts differently.

Comment: You say 2 inch intake and exhaust ... so this is a high efficiency condensing furnace with a power vented burner?  If that's right, it's the kind of information that would be helpful.  Maybe the venting fan has failed or is blocked.

Comment: More details….the burners light fine and run right until the main air blower turns on, then it blows out and has trouble relighting.  No error codes so I don’t think the gas is being shut off.  

I checked both flame sensor and primary temp limit. Neither appears to be shutting furnace down.

Comment: Also this is a new furnace in an existing duct system.

Comment: So I suspect either too much static pressure caused by ducts, or a gas issue (pressure too high or I need a high altitude kit).  High altitude kit is required for >7000 ft, I’m at 6500

Comment: Yes high efficiency. Ignition blower is working fine.  Pressure switches seem good.

Comment: Update….it’s the pressure switch on the induction blower.

Comment: I bypassed the switch (temporarily) and furnace runs great

Comment: Bypassing safety sensors so the furnace doesn't shut down doesn't mean it's running great.